# How is data type conversion done in Boolean/Number() constructor functions?

Tags: javascript, string, boolean

I've read that the reason `String()` constructor function can convert value to a string is its prototype which contains `toString()` method.

```
String(255); //"255" --> the result of the built-in toString() method
```

What is running "under the hood" here?

```
//Boolean 
Boolean(23);//true --> which method is invoked here?

//Number 
Number("34");//34 --> which method is invoked here?
```

Comment: ?? You're **calling** the functions, those are the methods that are being invoked

Comment: Also your presumption about how the String constructor works is incorrect. It does what it does because that's how it is specified to work.

Comment: `String(null)` is `'null'` but `null.toString()` throws an error

Comment: @Pointy _**You're calling the functions, those are the methods that are being invoked**_ yeah, I'm calling the functions. What methods are invoked here under the hood?

Comment: What difference does it make? Each JavaScript runtime is free to implement those constructor functions however it wants to. There may be *no* additional methods invoked; `Boolean(x)` could be implemented as `!!x` for example.